# MySQL Performance - 1 Million Records - Select Int before Text Field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Obviously selecting a text field among 1 million records would be slow and not recommended. Here are two possible solutions.

1. Break the database up giving each user his own database or table and therefore reducing the total records in each table dramatically.
2. Perform the SQL SELECT query to match a INT, where INT is the user ID, and then match the text field.

Option 1 would provide an obvious performance gain. But would option number 2 also provide a gain? In the statement, if we match the INT first, would this narrow the result set down to only the matching records and then perform the text field search. For example..

```
$user_id = 1001;
$domain_name = "mydomain.com";
$query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM domains_table WHERE user_id = $user_id && domain_name = $domain_name");
```

Where switching the position of user_id and domain_name in the above query would destroy performance. Does matching the user_id first offer an advantage here?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say about your query variations? Have you benchmarked them? Do you have Are you actually using a `TEXT` field for the domain name (why), or is that `VARCHAR`? Is that field indexed?

Comment: @DCoder I am using CHAR(36) instead of VARCHAR to get a performance gain there since that would be faster. Agree?

Comment: Why do you think 1 million records would be slow and not recommended?  1 million is quite tiny - make sure you have your columns indexed.  The first option sounds like a nightmare, and would possibly even be a performance loss.

Answer (score 6):

You keep saying things are "obvious." Have you measured them to compare, or are you making assumptions?

Using an index, searching for a string can be very quick. And certainly much quicker than searching for an integer if you *don't* have an index.

Once you use an index, the difference between an integer search and a string search is virtually imperceptible.

The best index would be a compound index on *both* columns:

```
ALTER TABLE domains_table ADD INDEX (user_id, domain_name);
```

Think of a telephone book. The book is sorted by last name, then by first name. If you search for "Smith, John" you narrow down the search to all the Smiths easily, and then within that subset, the names are sorted by firstname, so you can search for all those named John easily. That's how a compound index works.

If you don't have an index, it's like searching the whole telephone book cover-to-cover. This is called a *table scan*, and it gets more and more expensive, directly proportional to the size of your table. The size of a table also makes an index lookup slower, but this time it increases in cost proportional to the *logarithm* of the size of the table.

In other comments you learned that the optimizer can reorder terms in your WHERE clause for purposes of matching the order of columns in the index. This is true. That's the job of the query optimizer, and all RDBMS products you're likely to use (including MySQL) are smart enough to do this.

You might like to read my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really). Or a video of me presenting this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

There's also a great website with many tips on indexing: [Use the Index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/).

Answer (score 5):

A million-row table is not very big. Seriously.

If you create a compound index on the `user` and `domain` fields, the query you have shown in your question will be reasonably efficient without any changes to use integer identifiers.

Of course, integer identifiers are slightly more efficient **if** you don't have to run extra queries to find out what their values are.

Time you spend reading about how indexing and query execution planning works in MySQL will be time well spent.

Your first option (separate tables for separate users) is a far worse idea than proper indexing of a single table. That's for a lot of reasons, but prime among them is that it simply won't scale up gracefully if and when you start having thousands of users.

Answer (score 3):

If there is an index on user_id the query optimizer will figure out what is the correct order to match them in.

If you create a different database table for each user you're simply moving the load from the database to the filesystem .The filesystem will now have to find a database table out of tons of files. Not to mention there is an overhead when MySQL have to open a file and also a limit on the number of file descriptors it can have open.

Long story short: Option 1 will not provide a performance gain. Reordering the conditions in the query will not provide a performance gain -- the query optimizer already figures it out without your help. The only thing that will improve performance is having an index on user_id.

EDIT: Wanted to add something about compound indexes. As some answers have suggested a compound index on (user_id, domain) might work better for you. It will indeed further speed up the queries where you're matching against both user_id and domain. However, indexes are not free -- each one slows down insertion time and adding a new index may slow down others because all the indexes can no longer be held in memory.  So if you know you're always going to be querying against user_id, domain you should go ahead and use the compound index. However, if only some of your queries are going to be user_id, domain while others are going to be user_id and othercol, user_id and othercol2... Then your may be better of with an index on just user_id.

Comment: Out of interest: What happens when the user_id is not the only criteria?
        WHERE user_id = $user_id && domain_name = $domain_name"

Comment: Thanks. So what your saying is to put them all in one table, match the INT id first, text field second, and index the ID?

Comment: It doesn't matter what your criteria is. The query optimizer will reorder the criteria appropriately. If you criteria is ` domain_name = $domain_name && user_id = "user_id"`  it is smart enough to match by user_id first, especially if you have an index on user_id